# pug. Как вставить один переиспользуемый блок в другой блок?

Tags: pug

Есть блок с общей структурой, но разной вложенностью.

В моем случае это слайдер, есть окно, в этом окне произвольное количество слайдов. Я хочу написать один миксин, с такой структурой и использовать его по всему документу, но проблема в том, что есть слайдер картинок, а есть слайдер контента и соответственно внутренности будут отличаться, а обертка всегда одна.

Я хочу написать миксин, который бы принимал другой миксин. Не привязываюсь именно к миксинам. Но общая идея такая.

```html
// Этот блок хочу вставить
mixin insert()
  .insert

// Вставить вот в этот блок, внутрь .structure
mixin block-with-structure()
  .block-with-structure
    .structure
      // Вот сюда вставить.
      
// Чтобы, например, block-with-structure принимал в качестве аргумента миксин.
// Или можно было вызвать, например так:
  
  +block-with-structure()
    +insert()
    
    // И блок insert оказался на том месте, которое меня интересует
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут можно воспользоваться условием

```
mixin insert()
    .insert


mixin block-with-structure(insert)
    .block-with-structure
        .structure
            if insert == true
                +insert()
//- вызов с вложенностью .insert
+block-with-structure(true)

//- вызов без блока .insert
+block-with-structure()
```